# javax annotations problem

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb

I freaking loosing my mind on this:

I have this code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ANetApiResponseType", propOrder = {
    "resultCode",
    "messages"})
```

and I get this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from XmlAccessType to AccessType
```

I've googled , but all these problems usually occur because someone uses "AccessType" , but I already use the XmlAccessor/Access type !

Any ideas?

Comment: show us the whole code of the entity, and when do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting @XmlAccessorType, the bean can choose to only allow annotated fields to be serialized.

Have a link for your reference - http://www.caucho.com/resin/doc/jaxb-annotations.xtp#@XmlAccessorType